# How execute optaplanner-webexamples-7.6.0.Final in wildfly o tomcat 9?

Tags: web, optaplanner

I have problems to run opta planner web examples in tomcat 9.0 and I am not aware of executing it in wildfly, can someone give me a guide on how to do it?

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de Servlet especifica 
un nombre de servlet desconocido [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardCon
text.java:3101) at 
org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:879)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de Servlet especifica un nombre de servlet desconocido [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3101)
 at org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:879)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat doesn't support JAX-RS out of the box. It's not a JEE container. Use WildFly or another JEE container instead.